# understand and add qemu hmp command

Tags: c, qemu

is there a tutorial or explanation about how to add a qemu hmp command? I'm a beginer at qemu, so I"m looking for something that will cover the whole subject. 
P.S: a similar question was asked here before([adding a new "command" to QEMU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41321525/adding-a-new-command-to-qemu)) but no answers...)

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to QEMU but I happened to read a tiny part of qemu source code, I guess you might be looking for [this big switch-case](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/vl.c#.L3108) in the main function? It processes the options defined in the command line when you start qemu.

BTY, it seems that `QMP` is more suggested for higher level tools compared with `HMP`(see [here](http://wiki.qemu.org/HMP)).

Comment: now I understand that I had to add the C function to hmp.c, and the declaration to hmp.h, and finaly the command itself to hmp-commands.hx

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your question, so you mean you want to add a new command while you are debugging the vm. I didn't try that, but glad that you work it out.